# preview pane no longer showing folder contents

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, preview

Previously, I would click on a folder in the library pane (i.e. windows explorer's middle pane), and the folder contents, such as mp3 files, would show up in the preview pane. I could then select any file in the preview pane and play it.

After some updates yesterday, the preview pane no longer shows the folder content, but reads "no preview available". So now I have to double click on each folder in the library pane, which then shows the folder contents (such as individual mp3 files) in the library pane. I then select an mp3 file in the library pane, and now the preview pane shows the windows media player and I can play (preview) the file.

How do I get the preview pane to show the folder contents without me having to open the folder?  I have preview pane enabled, "Always show icons, never thumbnails" unchecked, "Show preview handlers in preview pane" checked.

Comment: You are saying that the preview pane used to show the contents of a folder if you clicked on it?

Comment: Yes - the preview pane would show all mp3 files located in a folder (the entire mp3 album "My Greatest Hits", just to use an example) when I single-clicked this folder in the library pane.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to see what updates were installed last time? Can you list it down here, so that it is easier for us to help you out. As of now, it seems preview is disable because of some update, which means your only option is to uninstall it.

Comment: There were (unfortunately) two changes made to the system at about the same time: a BIOS update, and SVN installation. If at all possible I'd like to avoid reverting to the old BIOS or uninstalling SVN.

Comment: Can you reinstall SVN? If yes, I will say, try to uninstall SVN and check if that works. If yes, ask SVN support, or add SVN tag here to get more help. BIOS update is not the cause of this.